# Detect a currently running CmdLet statically

Tags: c#, powershell, ilogger, powershell-cmdlet

I have a base Powershell `CmdLet` class that builds a `static IServiceProvider`. Classes that derive from this abstract `CmdLet` then leverage the `IServiceProvider` for DI. Because `IServiceProvider` is `static`, it's built **once per Powershell session**, rather than every time any derived CmdLet executes.

Various services include a constructor with a `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`. I would like the logs emitted by these services to be emitted in the Powershell session. For example, when `ILogger.LogTrace()` is called, I wish to pass that to the `CmdLet.WriteVerbose()` method.

I've created a `CmdletLogger` class along these lines:

```cs
public CmdletLogger(Cmdlet cmdlet, string categoryName): ILogger
{
  // ILogger interface implemented, using cmdlet.Write* methods.
}
```

I'd like to make a `CmdletLogger` available via `IServiceProvider`, but I cannot figure out how to **detect the currently running `CmdLet`** from a `CmdletLoggerProvider` class:

```cs
public class CmdLetLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider
{
    public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
    {
        // detect the currently running CmdLet here, so I can construct a CmdletLogger
    }
}
```

I realize that I could make the `IServiceProvider` non-static, and pass the `CmdLet` to the `CmdletLoggerProvider` class as I'm wiring the logging, but the performance impact of re-building the `IServiceProvider` for every `CmdLet` executed in a single `Powershell` session is ... not worth it.

I am hoping Powershell has something akin to [`IHttpContextAccessor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.ihttpcontextaccessor), but I've not been able to find such a thing.

For reference, the abstract `CmdLet` class looks like this:

```cs
public abstract class QboCmdlet : PSCmdlet
{
    protected static ServiceProvider Services
    {
        get
        {
            if (_services == null)
            {
                _services = new ServiceCollection()
                    // other stuff here
                    .AddLogging(options =>
                    {
                        // todo: inject a CmdLetLogger, but we need a CmdLet; how to detect?
                        // options.AddProvider(new CmdLetLoggerProvider());
                    })
                    .BuildServiceProvider();
            }
            return _services;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As I understand it, custom providers is for when you want to output/persist logs to storage not supported by the built-in providers, which, your question mentions nothing about - can you describe the use case here, why is it important with per-cmdlet loggers? Wouldn't a single logger implementation do?

Comment: Agreed; I would like the logs emitted by DI services to be emitted in the Powershell session. For example, when `ILogger.LogTrace()` is called, I wish to pass that to the `CmdLet.WriteVerbose()` method.  Question updated appropriately.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you're trying to do now. I'm afraid it's not possible - PowerShell's command runtime doesn't facilitate DI, so you'd have to explicitly obtain the logger in each cmdlet instance anyway.

Comment: Understood. I'm facilitating DI with my `QboCmdlet` class so that I can leverage a bunch of existing DI-friendly sugar from Powershell. It's working reasonably well except for this issue. I'm considering introducing a `static CurrentCmdlet` on `QboCmdlet` to address this problem, in a rather poor mimic of `IHttpContextAccessor`.